# how do you change a sidebar based on the router link angular 6?

Tags: html, css

```
router outlet html 
  <mat-sidenav-content color="accent" style="height: 100%;">
<div fxLayout="row" style="height: 100%;">
  <span fxFlex="fill" fxHide.lt-sm="true"></span>
  <div fxFlex.gt-xs="600px" fxFlex="100%" [fxShow]="location.path() === '' || (location.path().indexOf('/channel/') > -1 && location.path().indexOf('createpoll') == -1 && location.path().indexOf('createarticle') == -1)" style="margin-top:4em">
    <router-outlet name="main600"></router-outlet>    
  </div>
  <div fxFlex.gt-xs="900px" fxFlex="100%" [fxShow]="location.path() !== '' && (location.path().indexOf('/channel/') == -1 || location.path().indexOf('createpoll') > -1 || location.path().indexOf('createarticle') > -1)" style="margin-top:4em">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="300px" fxHide.lt-md="true" [fxShow]="location.path() === '' || (location.path().indexOf('/channel/') > -1 && location.path().indexOf('createpoll') == -1 && location.path().indexOf('createarticle') == -1)" style="margin-top:4em">
    <router-outlet name="side-bar"></router-outlet>    
  </div>

  <span fxFlex="fill" fxHide.lt-sm="true"></span>  
</div>
```

```
app-routing module follows here:


{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{path: 'home', redirectTo: "", pathMatch: "full"},
{
path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: LayoutComponent,
children: [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full", outlet:"main600"},
  {path: '', component: HomesidebarComponent, outlet:"side-bar", pathMatch: "full"},
   {
    path: 'community/:communityName', canActivateChild: [CommunityGuard],
    children: [
      {path: '', component: CommunityComponent},
      {path: 'about', component: CommunityaboutComponent},        
      {path: 'channels', component: ChannelsComponent, data: {roles:['member','owner','moderator']}},        
         {path: 'channel/:channelId',
    children: [
      {path: '', component: ChannelComponent, outlet:"main600", pathMatch: "full", data: {roles:['member','owner','moderator']}},
      {path: '', component: ChannelsidebarComponent, outlet:"side-bar", pathMatch: "full", data: {roles:['member','owner','moderator']}},        
      {path: 'createarticle', component: CreatearticleComponent, data: {roles:['member','owner','moderator']}},
      {path: 'createpoll', component: CreatepollComponent, data: {roles:['member','owner','moderator']}},
      {path: 'post/:postId', 
        children:[
          {path:'', component: PostComponent, outlet:"main600", pathMatch: "full", data: {roles:['member','owner','moderator']}},
          {path:'', component: ChannelsidebarComponent, outlet:"side-bar", pathMatch: "full", data: {roles:['member','owner','moderator']}},
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am having two router outlets, I am trying to implement routing functionality onto my **Angular application**, success. Routing works on the main container of my application and The problem I am having is that when to redirect to another component, like according to the particular router sidebar has to load but only on refresh it shows sidebar, (ChannelsidebarComponent) sidebar is not loading  and showing old (PostComponent) side bar 
 I am trying to understand how named outlets work in Angular 6. How to do according to the router change sidebar has to load

Can somebody please help me with this issue? I've tried going on tutorials to solve this, but I haven't gotten much luck.

thanks